# How to configure apache2 and Tomcat8 with mod_jk?

Tags: tomcat, apache2, tomcat8, mod-jk, kolab

i have some troubles with my apache2 and tomcat8 configuration.

```
<Virtualhost example.com>
JkMount /* ajp13_worker
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /opt/tomcat/public/my-webapp
ErrorLog /opt/tomcat/logs/error.log
CustomLog /opt/tomcat/logs/access.log common
<Directory /opt/tomcat/public/my-webapp>
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

this one works fine so every request from example.com are mapped to tomcat.

On the same Server runs a kolab mail server and if i try to login to example.com/roundcubemail or other web services with example.com/anypath there also mapped to my tomcat and this is rly bad.

How can i configure apache2 that they exclude example.com/anypath ?

here is my vhost for example.com/roundcubemail that not work :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Alias /roundcubemail /usr/share/roundcubemail/public_html/
```

Alias /webmail /usr/share/roundcubemail/public_html/

SetEnv no-gzip
    
    
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None

```
# php garbage collection for file-based sessions on debian is done via
# cronjob but roundcubemail uses mysql as storage during runtime which is
# not cleaned up by the cronjob. So reenable the default php gc method
php_admin_value session.gc_probability 1

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/(roundcubemail|webmail)
    RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{16}/(.*) /%1/$1 [PT,L]
</ifModule>
<ifModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all granted
</ifModule>
<ifModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
</ifModule>
```

thx 4 help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to exclude `/roudncubemail` context path from being mapped to Tomcat using mod_jk, you could just exlude it using a JkUnmount:

```
JkUnmount /roundcubemail ajp13_worker
JkUnmount /roundcubemail/* ajp13_worker
```

This way, your virtual host config should be just like this:

```
<Virtualhost example.com>
JkMount /* ajp13_worker
JkUnmount /roundcubemail ajp13_worker
JkUnmount /roundcubemail/* ajp13_worker
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /opt/tomcat/public/my-webapp
ErrorLog /opt/tomcat/logs/error.log
CustomLog /opt/tomcat/logs/access.log common
<Directory /opt/tomcat/public/my-webapp>
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```